# inherit all active variables of an input class

Tags: python, class

Imagine I have a class `A`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

and then I define a class `B` that is initialized by `A` (rather than take `A` as its base) and other parameters

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        if isinstance(a, A):
            self.a = a
```

The question is, suppose `A` has a gigantic amount of variables defined and shall be referred to in `B` frequently, is it possible to make `B` aware of those variables in `A`, so that in `B` I can do

```
self.x
```

rather than

```
self.a.x
```

?

I am aware this automatic inheritable of variables is kinda dangerous and even could be destructive, but typing many extra `self.a.x` looks a little clunky. Having the option to turn on this inheritance temporarily or in small snippets of code should be useful.

**EDIT**

`__dict__` brings up essentially everything, including `methods` and `functions`, possible to keep only numerical variables?

Comment: replicating `__dict__` is very close, but please have a look at my revised question: prefer inheriting only numerical variables (numbers and arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
class B(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self.a, attr):
            return getattr(self.a, attr)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Whenever you access an attribute of `B`, it will check if `a` has that attribute. If so, it'll return that instead. If not, it will lookup the attribute in `B` itself.

Comment: While the other two answers are probably the fanciest and simplest, this is by far the most flexible.  And updates to `a` are automatically "updated" in `b` as well.

Comment: I mainly want to use `a` inside `B`, rather than access outside of `B`, does it work in that way?

Comment: Yes, because when you write `self.foo` in methods of `B`, Python will call `__getattr__` to lookup the attribute and that means the above code will run.

Comment: I just checked the doc for __getattr__, it seems that python would only go to this if attr is not readily defined in `B`, here I am a bit confused now, when exactly is python gonna trigger this method.

Answer (score 1):

(Updated to not include methods):

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a, g):
        if isinstance(a, A):
            for k,v in a.__dict__.iteritems():
                if not callable(v):
                    self.__dict__[k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__dict__.update(a.__dict__)
```

Best practice in Python is usually not to check the type with `isinstance()` but to use "duck typing".  I don't know the full details of what you are doing, so I don't know if you have a legit reason to need the `isinstance()` check, but I wrote the above code without it.

This sets up your instance of `B` with the same member names as your instance of `A`, and with the same value references bound to those names.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of duck typing practice in oop. I use instance check here since in my source code `A` actually is very specific and I want only `A` in the definition of `B`